# Как получить обложку песни в qt5?

Tags: c++, qt5

Как можно вытащить из mp3 файла обложку посредством qt5? Чтобы в дальнейшем можно было бы записать картинку в отдельный файл.

Также я пытался использовать taglib, но у меня проблемы с его установкой. Выходят вот такие ошибки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так что хотелось бы на qt как-то это реализовать.

Comment: По ошибкам могу сказать, что IDE не может найти реализацию некоторых методов. Проверьте подключение библиотек, всё ли Вы добавили.

Comment: Самое что интересное я создал отдельный чистый проект без qt и подключил taglib. И он прекрасно заработал. Может это из-за qt?

Comment: Возможно ее надо как-то в .pro файле инклудить. Но я не знаю как(

Comment: Фак, не, это не от qt. Qt Проекты создаются и запускаются в x64. Решил запустить в x64 тот проект, на котором работает taglib. И чо. Он конечно не запустился. Видимо нужна lib для x64.

Comment: Мда... Дело было именно в этом...

Comment: Только увидел Ваши ответы, да, это именно отсутствие библиотек. Оформить это как правильный ответ?

Comment: Можно. Еще очень спасла такая вещь как vcpkg. С помощью него можно сделать lib x64 без лишнего геморроя.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Данная ошибка гласит, что система не может найти реализацию некоторых методов. Решением является добавление к проекту ссылок на верные статические библиотеки (.lib), которые содержат реализацию вышеупомянутых методов.